# how to fix JWT expired in next-auth?

Tags: node.js, next.js, next-auth

i have some trouble in login with google using next-auth, in local everything is ok, but in production, i have some error, i got the error after i choose google account,
this is error

```
[next-auth][error][OAUTH_CALLBACK_ERROR] 
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#oauth_callback_error JWT expired, now 1679915090, exp 1679893540 {
error: RPError: JWT expired, now 1679915090, exp 1679893540
       at Client.validateJWT (/app/node_modules/openid-client/lib/client.js:956:15)
       at Client.validateIdToken (/app/node_modules/openid-client/lib/client.js:745:60)
       at Client.callback (/app/node_modules/openid-client/lib/client.js:488:18)
       at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
       at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
       at async oAuthCallback (/app/node_modules/next-auth/core/lib/oauth/callback.js:109:16)
       at async Object.callback (/app/node_modules/next-auth/core/routes/callback.js:52:11)
       at async AuthHandler (/app/node_modules/next-auth/core/index.js:201:28)
       at async NextAuthHandler (/app/node_modules/next-auth/next/index.js:24:19)
       at async /app/node_modules/next-auth/next/index.js:60:32 {
     name: 'OAuthCallbackError',
     code: undefined
   },
   providerId: 'google',
   message: 'JWT expired, now 1679915090, exp 1679893540'
 }
```

and this is my code

```
export default NextAuth({
    providers: [
        GoogleProvider({
            clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET
        })
    ],
    secret: process.env.SECRET,
    callbackUrl: process.env.CALLBACK_URL,
    debug: false,
    jwt: {
        maxAge: 3 * 24 * 60 * 60,
    },
})
```

i can sign in with google without error

Answer (score 1):

In my experience this happens when your computer is in an invalid timezone. Check if your browser alerts you of a warning because of mismatching times, this probably causes your JWT to time out because of server-browser time mismatch.